# Symfony2 SonataAdmin error saving Entity with many to many relation with Media. Message: Entity Was not configured to cascade persist

Tags: symfony-sonata

When I try to save an Entity linked with a many to many relation with the Media Entity of Sonata i get the error: Entity Was not configured to cascade persist

I have created the Entity class between the two tables, named EntityMedias.

Now I have 
  Entity -1----N- EntityMedias -N----1- Media

And the annotations are set in the EntityMedias two manytoone relations, one related to Entity and the other one related to Media.

How can I configure the Entity with cascade Persist?
I have tried to add the option cascade=persist to the column notation, but it doesn't work.

In EntityAdmin I used sonata_type_collection to show the $entityMedias relation inside the Entity.

All work fine if I don't add any media to the new Entity.

Any help will be apreciated

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to observe the syntax for Doctrine to actually pick this up. If you have

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Entity", mappedBy="medias") 
 */
protected $medias;
```

you would have to turn this into that:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Entity", mappedBy="medias", cascade={"persist"}) 
 */
protected $medias;
```

I took this from the relevant documentation [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#owning-side-and-inverse-side) and [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations).